# threading for a windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have made a service which reads an xml. In the xml i have Input directory and output directory. The service picks the files in the input directory and renames them and moves them to the output directory. I want to implement threading in the service. I want it to pick one node of xml in one thread and other in the other. Or it would even be good if irrespective of nodes one thread picks the first 10 operations to be performed and the next the next 10 and so on. So that all the nodes are processed in a parallel fashion. Can anyone help me on this? i tried reading through a few threading tutorials but could not gain much through them. The service code is as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Data.xml");
            int count = doc.SelectNodes("Data/DataClass").Count;
            for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                string xpath = "/Data/DataClass[" + i + "]";
                XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
                XmlNodeList subnode = node.ChildNodes;
                string pathO = "";
                string pathI = subnode[0].InnerText;
                string prefix = subnode[2].InnerText;
                string freq = subnode[3].InnerText;
                string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(pathI);
                node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath));
                doc.Save("Data.xml");

                foreach (string filename in filenames)
                {
                    pathO = subnode[1].InnerText;
                    pathO = pathO + "\\" + prefix;
                    string fname = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                    pathO = pathO + fname;
                    System.IO.File.Move(filename, pathO);

                }
            }
```

Comment: you should abandon idea of thinking how many threads you need and just let Imran to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach, check the following code, its simple , i've modified your code here only so check it with VS (there maybe small changes as per your requirement).

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Data.xml");
int count = doc.SelectNodes("Data/DataClass").Count;
Parallel.For(0,doc.SelectNodes("Data/DataClass").Count-1,i =>
{
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectNodes("Data/DataClass")[i];
    XmlNodeList subnode = node.ChildNodes;
    string pathO = "";
    string pathI = subnode[0].InnerText;
    string prefix = subnode[2].InnerText;
    string freq = subnode[3].InnerText;
    string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(pathI);
    doc.Save("Data.xml");
    foreach (var filename in filenames)
    {
        pathO = subnode[1].InnerText;
        pathO = pathO + "\\" + prefix;
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        pathO = pathO + fname;
        System.IO.File.Move(filename, pathO);
    }
}
);
```

Don't remove the child node inside Parallel loop so i removed the following line 
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

Learn more about Task Parallel Liberary (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx)  for parallel processing features given.

Comment: the filename part to which you applied the parallel foreach is for various files in a directory. i am trying to implement it on the xml nodes(i.e. on various directories). i tried doing it on the for loop above but it doesnot seem to work properly.

Comment: i tried exactly wat you have posted in the answer but it just keeps giving an object reference null answer for the last node in xml when i am pretty sure there is data. And also at times it moves only half the files in the directory specified and leaves rest few. So in short not working properly.

Comment: try by prevent removing child node inside parallel loop